# Circle inscribed in spherical triangle

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, spherical-geometry

Let $u,v,w \in S^2$ and let $[u,v,w]$ be a spherical triangle. I want to find its inscribed circle. However, I don't know how to approach this problem. Would someone please explain?

In my understanding, one needs to somehow find the altitudes of the spherical triangle and then the point of its intersection (circumcentre)? Then what about the radius?

Comment: The bisectors of the vertices are concurrent at the incenter.

Comment: @Marc, If a duplicate, not of the post linked.

Comment: Google "Spherical trigonometry" go to the wiki link (the first one on the list), the first reference is a book by Todhunter http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/19770 ... There is a chapter that deals with the cicumcircle & incircle for a spherical triangle.

Comment: The altitudes of a triangle will trisect at the orthocenter. An equivalent result does exist for a spherical triangle ... I will supply the proof upon request. ... I think you need to look at the trisection of the edge bisectors for the construction of the incenter ... again I can tell you that such a construction exist for a spherical triangle & will supply a proof upon request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $o$ is the center of the sphere, consider planes $ouv$, $ovw$ and $owu$. The bisector planes of the angles, formed by any two of those planes, meet at a common line $r$, having the same distance from the planes.

You can then construct the plane passing by line $r$ and perpendicular to plane $ouv$: that plane cuts arc $uv$ at some point $p$. The circle having $r$ as perpendicular axis and passing through $p$ is the requested incircle.